# Building QGIS with Visual Studio 2015 on windows x64?

Tags: qgis, visual-studio, windows-10

I tried to follow the guide at [github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL), hence I encounter problem after problem (Now I have problems with: `MSBuild.exe  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:`, earlier I couldn't find any c++ paths etc.) I assume that I have done some mistake and missed something running the installation.

I'm curious if there is anyone that recently have build QGIS on Windows(10) with Visual Studio(2015) and can give some advise what to change in the .bat file, where I can set the path to bison and flex in cmake, what and where I shall use the Ninja.exe file that I downloaded according the guide.

Comment: While **using** QGIS is a GIS activity, ***compiling*** QGIS is a software development activity, much more appropriate for  [so] proper.

Comment: You can use alternative build of QGIS based on NextGIS Borsch. Get it here: https://github.com/nextgis/nextgisqgis. Use CMake GUI to configure your build.